# Pasting text creates extra space

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application i need to paste text into a `UITextView` and view it row by row in a `UITableView`, however i have come across an unusual problem where when i paste text inside the application it creates an extra unused row and moves to the text to the row below it. [image: For example]. In the image you can see that i enter the text at the top in a TextView and it creates an empty row each time it moves down.

Heres my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];;


return cell;
}
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


 return [listArray count];

}



-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

listArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];

 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

This doesn't happen for everything i paste but does happen for basically the one main piece of text i need to enter into the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, you can remove extra space by the following way

```
NSString *yourText = @" remove extra space  ";
NSString *finalText = [yourText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: i just get an unused variable warning for final text.

Comment: because you did not use this variable anywhere

Comment: even when i change it to textView it still doesn't change.

Comment: Is there something i'm missing here?

Comment: give me your text view's frame size

Comment: do you mean the actual view size? if so that is 414 * 127